# Determine if UIViewController is inside Container View

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

Is it possible to detect if a UIViewController is inside a container view, compared to for instance being displayed modally, being inside a UINavigationViewController and so on?

Edit: to clarify the reason for this question: I have a VC that sometimes is displayed as a Form Sheet, other times as a child VC inside another VC (in a Container View). I want to be able to check how the VC is actually displayed (Form Sheet or in Container View).

Comment: Be careful here as a UIViewController simply coordinates UIViews. It technically doesn't display anything and isn't really contained in a UIView.  Can you be more specific about the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: It's a little hard to answer this in the abstract. In what situation would you not know whether it was in a container view or not (after all you presumably created the storyboard, and would know that)? Can you be more specific about why you would need this information?

Comment: Your edit is essentially asking the same thing. The "container" view you are referring to does not actually exist. It only gets drawn in a storyboard to help designing. All that happens is the `view` of the "contained" view controller gets added as a subview of the `view` belonging to the "parent" view controller. You can do it in code... `[self.view addSubview:someViewController.view];` this is all that is happening.

Comment: Like @dboals said. Forget about containing view controllers etc... what is the problem you are trying to solve. What is the function you are hoping to achieve by doing something like this. There is probably a better way of doing it.

Comment: Edited the question to explain the reason for the question.

Answer (score 4):

```
parentViewController property is set only if you are inside a container view.
```

See -->
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController

EDIT:

as to check the type do something like this.

```
UIViewController * parentController = self.parentViewController;
if (parentController != nil && [parentController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
{
    // code
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `parentController != nil` condition.

Comment: It's not as simple as this. The parentViewController property will be non-nil if the controller is embedded in any type of container controller -- that includes all of Apple's canned ones like UINavigationController, UITabBarController, and UISplitViewController. I'm not sure if the OP is asking to distinguish between those and a custom container view? If so, you would have to see if the parentViewController is non-nil, and not any of those Apple classes.

Comment: @redelmar, yeah for some reason my eyes only saw the question up to the word modally, but yes he would need to check for all the canned Apple types or if he knows the possible customViewController types he could also simple compare against those.  Depends on what he is doing with this.

Comment: UIViewController has a method named -navigationController!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift3, using

```
if let parentVC = self.parent{ //no embeded
    if parentVC is UINavigationController //no embedded{
       ...
    } else {//embeded
       ...
    }
 } else {//presented
    ...
 }
```

express showing current view controller from navigation bar; otherwise
embedded by parent view controller(for example, ViewController with one view embedding with one UITableViewController).

if self.parent == nil, it is presented.  Hope for helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little snippet that shows all the subviews of a view, so if you pass it a top-level view, you can see your entire subview tree.  Pass @"  " to Indent to make the subtrees indent a bit, then copy it from the debugger console and paste it into a text editor like Bbedit.

```
- (void) viewAllSubviews:(UIView *) topView Indent:(NSString *) indent  {
for (UIView * theView in [topView subviews]){
    NSLog(@"%@%@", indent, theView);
    if ([theView subviews] != nil)
        [self viewAllSubviews:theView Indent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",indent]];
}
```

}

You can use something like this to check for your container view.

Answer (score 0):

UIViewController has a property navigationController, and a property tabBarController. See [UIVIewController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926)

```
if(self.navigationController) {
    //you are inside a navigation controller
}
```